# Apache Virtual hosts aren't working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am trying to create two port-based virtual hosts. One of the sites is 'loading' until it times out, and the other shows the default "It works" from the default vhost.

My apache2 conf is here

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot "/home/tnewhook/webSites/solar"    
ErrorLog /home/tnewhook/webSites/solar/error.log
CustomLog /home/tnewhook/webSites/solar/access.log "combined"

<Directory "/home/tnewhook/webSites/solar">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

     RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
       Options +Indexes
</Directory>
    LogLevel error
</VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:82>
DocumentRoot "/home/tnewhook/webSites/testing/"
ErrorLog  "/home/tnewhook/webSites/testing/error.log"
 CustomLog /home/tnewhook/webSites/testing/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/tnewhook/webSites/testing/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

I can't figure out what the difference is, and why one would work, and one wouldn't. In addition, NOTHING is being written to either access.log or error.log for either vhost. Root owns the files, and only root can write to them, if that makes a difference.

It was working fine this morning for the first vhost, and when I tried to add another vhost via webmin, the whole thing went belly up. Any and all advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: I changed both access.log and error.log to 777 for both virtual hosts. Neither are getting written to.

Comment: Check in you webservers _main_ error log what the problem is. If these are you total configurations, I'd say a missing `</VirtualHost>`

Comment: the file DOES have a </VirtualHost>

Comment: So, we have been supplied an incomplete rather then a complete configuration, which makes things a bit harder... But well, your webservers main error log usually will tell you why stuff doesn't work, any luck on that front?

Comment: The error log doesn't say anything interesting - just several normal restart operations that I tried after changing various config files.

`    [Tue Oct 15 06:59:37.235760 2013] [core:notice] [pid 3821] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 15 07:00:44.868733 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3821] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 15 07:00:44.963909 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3821] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.4-1+debphp.org~precise+1 configured -- resuming normal operations`

Comment: I commented out the error log directives for the vhosts in apache2.conf, and it seems to have no effect. I can't figure out WHERE the logs are getting written for the vhosts. it's not in /var/apache2/log or VHOST FOLDER/error.log. Apache2.conf says ServerRoot /etc/apache2 and ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log. Nothing is being written to /etc/apache2/error.log

Comment: OK, does `netstat` report Apache both listening on port 81 & 82? Do you have a firewall configured that might block the one that is timing out? And do you have _any_ other vhost configured on those ports?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39289/discussion-between-trevor-newhook-and-wrikken)

Comment: go figure - I can access the site if I use 127.0.0.1:81 or :82, but not 'localhost' I definitely don't understand THAT.

Comment: Hm, what does `localhost` resolve to for you? And: do you have any proxy settings in your browser or OS which may cause them to resolve differently? (For instance in my office, I specifically created a `wpad.dat` for proxy-autoconfiguration, which told devs browsers that localhost/127.0.0.1 and the like should connected to DIRECT, not via proxy).

Comment: Localhost:81 and localhost:82 just time out,  but the other ports I'm listening on, but don't have virtual hosts on (*.83, *.84, and *.85) load just fine. I don't have any proxy settings/programs in my browser or computer. My configuration was working fine until the other day, when I tried to add a virtual host via Webmin.

Comment: Hm, could you remove _all_ `log` directives from your vhosts? It could very well be a DNS issue with a certain log-format or the like. If that works, examine 2 things (1) does your log format require a dns lookup? if so, remove that portion until it doesn't (2) if it doesn't, examine with `lsof` whether other processes are locking your access logs.